# can two project ( MVC5 and ASP.NET CORE3.1) use the same database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I made another project and didn't connect to the database yet. The database has configured with MVC5 patterns which include `Membership provider` and some `depreciated functions such as SQLRoleProvider`. It is working great on MVC5 project and I made a new ASP.NET CORE 3.1 project below MVC5 project. I can't use the current login function so I should make a new login function fit to the core version.
I am lost from here. Do I just put ```GetConnectionSTring`` as we do with EF? But I am not using EF but I use LLBLgen for dataaccess layer. How can I use the database to authenticate from the MVC5 version database?

I also wonder how I write a code for login in .Net Core loginController. I have to make a custom authentication because I am trying to access database which has been made by MVC5. Can you guys recommend anything that I can look up?

Comment: You can just connect to the database with asp.net core, its just a database. i can even connect to it from node.js if i wanted to.

Comment: @sommmen do I connect with DbContext(EF)?